# Which one is better for custom errors: HTML or View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I've been thinking what would be a better to render when an error occurs in my web application, using a html page as an error page because it will always run unless my whole server is down or using dynamic server-side pages as they might be affected by the problem which causes the error so the system may end up with infinite loop to render error page. But I may  not be thinking thoroughly so I am asking you about what you think about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends largely on two factors:

- Whether you want to reuse layout views to integrate the error page into the site design
- Whether you want to include any dynamic content in the error page (user monikers, links etc)

In either case, you will need to use Views rather than an Html page. The latter has the advantage of not being able to cause further exceptions. However, a carefully-coded OnException method in the controller used with a view can provide a better user experience than a static Html page.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your error pages static html.

If you use dynamic views are there is a problem with the layout page for example - your error page will not render and as you mention you will end up in a infinite loop.

If you want to capture exceptions and alert you to it have a look at Elmah.